# Why do I get open error when reading from file in assembly?

Tags: file, assembly, error-handling, x86, x86-16

I am trying to read a string from a file and print it on the screen, but I always get an error at opening the file. Why is this happening? What is wrong with the code or with the file? PS: the file is in the same folder as the .asm file.

```
ASSUME cs: code, ds:data
data SEGMENT
        inputFile db "D:\AC\input.txt", 0
        openingError db 'An error has occured at opening the file!$'
        readingError db 'An error has occured at reading the file!$'
        s1 db 10 dup(?)
        ls db 0
        handle dw ?
data ENDS
code SEGMENT
start:
       mov ax,data
       mov ds,ax
                 ;open the file
       mov ah, 3dh
       mov al, 0
       mov dx, offset inputFile
       int 21h
       mov handle, ax
       jc openError
                ;read 10 bytes from the file into s1
       mov ah, 3fh
       mov bx, handle
       mov cx, 10
       mov dx, offset s1
       int 21h
       jc readError

       openError:
            mov ah, 09h
            mov dx, offset openingError
            int 21h
            jmp the_end

      readError:
            mov ah, 09h
            mov dx, offset readingError
            int 21h
            jmp the_end

            ;close file
     mov ah, 3eh
     mov bx, handle
     int 21h
            ;print string on the screen
     lea dx, s1
     mov ah, 09h
     int 21h

     the_end:
     mov ax,4C00h
     int 21h
code ENDS
END start
```

Comment: Did you look at your filename in memory with a debugger? Might be the ' \'  needs special treatment.

Comment: Yes, I did. I also tried '/' but it still didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Did youi forget to actually open the file? Where is the `int 21`?

```
mov ah, 3dh
mov al, 0
lea dx, inputFile
int 21h
jc openingError
mov handle, ax
```

Comment: Indeed, I forgot the interrupt. But why 20h and not 21h? However, I still get the open error for 21h, and for 20h it doesn't work at all.

Comment: 20 was a typo which I fixed.

Comment: I posted some code which should work if the file exists. Did you do it like this? If it doesn't work, you should edit your posting and show the changed code.

Comment: I cannot edit the post until I give more specifications (it appears I have more code than details) so it still doesn't work